# Store Ajax div content in a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have a problem with variables. I have a website using only Jquery which means that that I use `#p1`, `#p02`, ..., to navigate from one page to another.

I made an Ajax call which prints an id that I need in order to view my content. This id is printed in a div. The problem is that when I store the div in a variable like this:

```
    $variable="<div class='something'></div>";
```

I can echo the variable but CAN'T use it in order to make queries. I know this is but programming but if I use sessions instead the identity didn't updated at all from page to page because of the using of `#p01` instead of `p1.php`.

I also added the ajax.js file if this help you in order to advise me. The ajax.js file sends an identity to Ajax_page.php then I store this $_POST variable in a SESSION and then I echo this varible in Ajax_page.php. When i echo this variable it also printed in the div which is in the   **Show_content_page.php**. I want the contents of that div. I want to use this div contents(identity) in order to make my php queries. Thats all.

Is there any way to make the `$variable` useful?

Here are the to sample files

**Ajax_page.php**

```
    <?php 
    session_start(); 
    if(!empty($_POST['show_an_anetoix'])  ){
        $_SESSION['anetoix_id']=$_POST['show_an_anetoix'];
    }  
    echo $_SESSION['anetoix_id'];
    ?>
```

**Show_content_page.php**

```
    <div id="p1" >
    <?php 
    $variable="<div class='something'></div>"; 
    echo $variable; //no problem
    function_test($variable); //problem
    ?>
    </div>
```

The ajax.js

```
/* Pass data with changePage */
$(document).on("pageinit", "#p1", function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.anetoix_class', function(){   
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#p02", {
            stuff: this.id,
            transition: "flip"
            });
    });
});       

/* retrieve data and run function to add elements */
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
    if (data.toPage[0].id == "p02") {
        var stuff = data.options.stuff;   
        var data = {"show_an_anetoix": stuff,};

 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",  
 url: "../show_an_anetoix.php",
 data: data,
      success: function(response) 
      {$(".show_an_anetoix").html(response);}
    });            
 }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: _if I use sessions instead the identity didnt updated at all from page to page_ - are you declaring `session_start();` on `Show_content_page.php`?

Comment: please include your AJAX code in your question

Comment: Yes i have session_start in both pages but as i said i do not refresh the pages at all. I use #p1, #p2 to navigate from one page to another. the session will take effect only if i reload the page. For example i have p1 which have a session_id="23" ,everything is ok. Then i use href="p2" to navigate to p2 which has session_d="24" this is not possible because i have to reload the p2 to get the new id.

Comment: #verbumSapienti I added the ajax code also ..

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you mean. Are you asking, can you use a PHP variable in ajax? If so, I would do something like this:

```
<script>

$ajax_variable = "<?php echo $php_variable; ?>";

</script>
```

Comment: No what i mean is that the div contains an identity and i can not use it because is  in a div . I want to use it in php in order to make queries but it seems not possible

Comment: +1 and welcome to SO. Note that it might be useful to mention JSON encoding/decoding in order to avoid quote issues (imagine what would happen if `$php_variable` in your case was: `<div class="a"></div>`).

Comment: Why store the <div> code in the variable? Why not try this? $variable="123"; echo "<div class='something'>" . $variable . "</div>";

Comment: My friend i use json in my ajax call. First i take the $_POST variable came from ajax in the php page after i store the $_POST variable in a session because i dont want to lose it. Then i print the session variable in a div but the the problem is starting..

Comment: Ah ok... so you need to strip the HTML out in the PHP variable. How about this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php so.... $variable = strip_tags($variable);

Comment: I tried this but if i do this the id will no longer exists. This is because the class in the id is called by the ajax call in order to print the id in this div. I really dont know what to do... Check out my site www.anetoi.com#p02 to see in action my problem...